# AWS IoT hub SQL: Unexpected character '$'

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, mqtt, iot

I want to set up the just-in-time-registration atIoT core at Amazon AWS with help of this tutorial:
https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/iot/just-in-time-registration-of-device-certificates-on-aws-iot/ 
If the registration succeeds, a mqtt message is pushed to the topic 
$aws/events/certificates/registered/
So to add a device and set the certificate as active, i want to add a rule to trigger a lambda.

I tried to set the rule via aws cli but i get the same error as in the management console.

```
SELECT * FROM $aws/events/certificates/registered/#
```

I get this error: "An error occurred (SqlParseException) when calling the CreateTopicRule operation: Unexpected character '$'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enclose the topic in single quotes:

```
SELECT * FROM '$aws/events/certificates/registered/#'
```